# Transition Of CSS Button Not Working

Tags: css

I have created a ghost button in CSS and everything is working perfectly well except that the transition of the word after which the user hovers his mouse on the original word is not moving. I want the word "View Details: to move 5px to the left on mouse hover. This might only need one line of code. Thx (-:

```css
.btn_action_1 {
  border: 5px solid #000 !important;
  /* Change button border color */
  color: #000 !important;
  /* Change button text color */
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn_action_1 span {
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}
.btn_action_1 .ico_arrow {
  background: url(ico_arrow_w.png) 0 center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}
.btn_action_1:hover {
  background: #000 !important;
  /* Change button background color when mouse over */
  color: #fff !important;
  /* Change button text color when mouse over */
}
.btn_action_1:hover span {
  left: -10px;
}
.btn_action_1:hover .ico_arrow {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  left: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .btn_action_1 {
    padding: 18px 30px;
  }
}
.btn_action_1:not(:hover)>.hover,
.btn_action_1:hover> .default {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="default">Product Name</span>
  <span class="hover">View Details</span>
  <i class="ico_arrow"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML too.

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: i have added my HTML to the post @Turnip. please check it

Comment: What is a ghost button? Your snippet looks like a plain link

Comment: hey @TheReveller a ghost button is a button whereby when it is placed anywhere on your site, you will be able to see the background layer. so it is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="btn_action_1">
  <span class="ico_arrow"></span>
  <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.btn_action_1 {
  border: 5px solid #000 !important;
  /* Change button border color */
  color: #000 !important;
  /* Change button text color */
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn_action_1 span {
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.btn_action_1 .ico_arrow {
  background: url(ico_arrow_w.png) 0 center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.btn_action_1:hover {
  background: #000 !important;
  /* Change button background color when mouse over */
  color: #fff !important;
  /* Change button text color when mouse over */
}

.btn_action_1:hover span {
  left: -10px;
}

.btn_action_1:hover .ico_arrow {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  left: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .btn_action_1 {
    padding: 18px 30px;
  }
}

.btn_action_1:not(:hover)>.hover,
.btn_action_1:hover> .default {
  display: none
}
```

guessing the HTML code here

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grNpPq

this seems to work, on chrome 52.

Comment: yes that is correct @user5322657, but the word is not moving why?

Comment: what browser are you using? text is moving in chrome 52

Comment: i am using chrome but after placing the last three lines of code in my css, the transition has stopped.